# pandas dataframe - increase values of a subset of a timeframe on a multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

The following code worked for me on pandas 12.0, but on pandas 13 no longer works (processing time @1 min per record, previously 200k records were processed in an hour or so).

I suspect there's a more elegant way of achieving the same result.  Would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction.

I create the dataframe like so:

```
pubs = ['pub1','pub2','pub3','pub4','pub5']

panel = pd.Panel(np.random.randn(2,2200,5), items=['variableA','variableB'], major_axis=pd.date_range('20110101', periods=2200), minor_axis=pubs)
df_sub = panel.to_frame()
df_sub.ix[:] = 0
```

I increment values like this:

```
startDate = time.ctime(time.mktime(time.strptime(meh,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")))
TempRng = pd.date_range(startDate, periods=75)
for eachDay in TempRng:
    df_sub.ix[eachDay,pubID]['variableA'] +=1
    df_sub.ix[eachDay,pubID]['variableB'] += 5
```

^^It's this last part which used to work fine a month ago, but now grinds to a halt.  On a different machine which still has the older version of pandas, the processing speed is acceptable.

What is the correct way of making this increment?

Comment: the 2nd part of your example has a lot of variables which are not defined. pls make a copy-pastable example.

Comment: Hi Jeff,  I've edited to remove most of the variables.  PubID will be a single value from the pubs[] list at the top.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse what you are doing and iterate over the smaller number of pubs. This will be order of magnitudes faster. Ix/loc is very fast when setting big ranges / slices. Using it for a small number of changed many times is inefficient.

```
In [57]: df = df_sub.reset_index()

In [58]: mask = df.minor == 'pub1'

In [59]: df.loc[mask,'variableA'] = 1

In [60]: df.loc[mask,'variableB'] = 5

In [61]: df.loc[mask,'variableA'] = df.loc[mask,'variableA'].cumsum()

In [62]: df.loc[mask,'variableB'] = df.loc[mask,'variableB'].cumsum()

In [64]: df.set_index(['major','minor']).head(20)
Out[64]: 
                  variableA  variableB
major      minor                      
2011-01-01 pub1           1          5
           pub2           0          0
           pub3           0          0
           pub4           0          0
           pub5           0          0
2011-01-02 pub1           2         10
           pub2           0          0
           pub3           0          0
           pub4           0          0
           pub5           0          0
2011-01-03 pub1           3         15
           pub2           0          0
           pub3           0          0
           pub4           0          0
           pub5           0          0
2011-01-04 pub1           4         20
           pub2           0          0
           pub3           0          0
           pub4           0          0
           pub5           0          0

[20 rows x 2 columns]
```

In 0.14 you will be able to do this to directly index (and set) the 2nd level

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice

df_sub.loc[idx[:,'pub1'],:] = 1
```

Comment: That's not quite what I'm trying to achieve - I was looking to +1 / +5 to whatever value might already be in that location.  But thanks for taking the time so show me this approach - I'll see if I can use this to get what I need (until then - put a big sticky on other machine to remind myself not to move on from 12.0 until I have a concrete alternative :)

Comment: Ok, that's not what your example does. If you start off with all nans,then put in your starting conditions this will work (as cumsum will basically ignore the nans)